# Excel: How ro write Mutiple IFs in in same formula and formula not pulling correct value?

Tags: excel

I am having trouble with the formula below as it is not pulling the correct value or perhaps the formula needs to be tweaked.

```
=IF((AND(Sheet1!H10>65,D17>=65)),Sheet2!D$47,VLOOKUP(D17,Sheet2!$A$2:$K$51,4,FALSE))
```

What I am basically trying to do is if the value in H10 is greater than 65 and the value in D17 > or = 65 then pull the value from sheet2 D47 cell. Other wise use vlookup to lookup the value.

I have a case where The value in D17 =66 however, it is returning the value based on the vlookup and not Sheet2-D47.

Also, is it possible to have multiple IFs in the same formula?

Comment: What sheet is `D17` on?  Perhaps it should really be `Sheet1!D17`?

Comment: you say the value in D17 was 66, but what was the value in H10 at that same time (note blanks count as 0)?  you used an AND function, so both cases need to be true to pull from D47.

Comment: Forward Ed. Value in H10 is 70

Comment: Code Different: No, the formula is on sheet3 and D17 is on Sheet 3 thanks

Answer (score 0):

Where are you writing the formula? If your formula isn't on sheet1 D17 might be pointing at the wrong cell. It sounds like it would be pointing to the correct D17 if your vlookup is working though. Remember with an AND formula, all conditions need to be true. Is H10>65? if not then even with D17 = 66 then if statement will return false and execute the vlookup.

And yes you can have nested if statements (I believe 7 is the most). but you can do:

```
=if(A5>5, if(A5 = 7, "A5 is greater than 5 and equals 7", "A5 is greater than 
 5, but does not equal 7"),"A5 is less than 5)
```

Comment: The formula is in Sheet 3

Comment: Yes H10 is > 65. H10 is 70

Comment: I used =IF(AND(Sheet1!H10>65,D17>=65),Sheet2!D$47,VLOOKUP(D17,Sheet2!$A$2:$K$51,4,FALSE)) and returned the the result from Sheet2!D47. So the formula should work as long as your Sheet1!H10 > 65 and Sheet3!D17 is >= 65. It also worked for having one of the values less than 65 returning the Vlookup. I noticed you formula has an extra set of brackets around the AND but shouldn't matter and your Vlookup range is larger than required, which again, shouldn't matter. So, either the issue is with your values or I'm not sure. If you attach the workbook I could take a look?

Comment: Thanks!. What I did I Copied H10 from sheet1 to sheet 3 and then it worked.

Comment: As For nested IF statements can you please see below it is actually giving an error: =IF((AND(B11>65,D15>65)),Sheet1!D$47,VLOOKUP(D15,Sheet1!$A$2:$K$51,4,FALSE)),IF((AND(B11>61,D15>61)),Sheet1!D$44,VLOOKUP(D15,Sheet1!$A$2:$K$51,4,FALSE))

Comment: The error is when you start your 2nd IF. You are technically starting it at a 4th a portion of the 1st IF stmt, which you can't do. An IF stmt is =IF(conditionalTest,valueIfTrue,valueIfFalse) so if you want to run a nested IF statement the 2nd IF will have to run when the conditional stmt is or isn't met. So, you could do =IF(AND(B11>65,D15>65),Sheet1!D$47,IF(‌​AND(B11>61,D15>61),Sheet1!D$44,VLOOKUP‌​(D15,Sheet1!$A$2:$K$‌​51,4,FALSE))                  This is doing: if the 1st test is true, return Sheet1!D47, if it false, check if the 2nd condition is met & return the D44 value or the Vlookup